# Why is this section of code being ignored?

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code, `set_black_hole()` is never called. Why?

I added small print statements to both `set_black_hole()` and `set_data()`. `Set_data()` gets called repeatedly as expected, but `set_black_hole()` is never called. When I run a debugger and set a breakpoint just before the call for `set_black_hole()`, it just skips to the if() statement right after it.

Thoughts?

Is this a template specific issue by chance?

```
/******************************************************************
*   build_list
*     add new items to the list until input is exhausted
*/

template <typename T>
void List<T>::build_list(ifstream &fin)
{
   T *pT;
   bool readSuccess;    // successful read of object data
   bool storeSuccess;   // successful node addition

   pT = new T;

   readSuccess = pT->set_black_hole(fin); // fill the T object
   if (readSuccess) {
       storeSuccess = add_node(pT);
   }

   while (true)
   {
      storeSuccess = false;
      readSuccess = pT->set_data(fin); // fill the T object
      if (fin.eof())
      {
         delete pT;
         break;
      }

      // insert object data into the list
      if (readSuccess)
         storeSuccess = add_node(pT);
      else   // something bad happened during node setup
      {
         delete pT;
         fatal_err(BAD_SET_DATA);
      }
      if (!storeSuccess)   // something bad happened during store
         fatal_err(BAD_ADD_NODE);
   }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps the code for that function was inlined?  If you put a print statement in that function, do you get output?

Comment: You're never assigning to `readSuccess` and then you check it in `if (readSuccess)` which is UB. May or may not be the reason for this particular bug though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth as I said in the description, I added print statements to both, and that function is being skipped entirely.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I had incorrectly pasted the code, that line is fixed now, but that line was still after the call for set_black_hole() so it's unrelated either way (I think).

Comment: In that case, it's very difficult to say.  It's likely that you're looking at the side-effect of form of undefined behaviour (assuming it's not something trivial like you forgot to recompile).  Can you construct a [test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @Justin technically it doesn't matter where the UB occurs, it can affect things before it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recompiling/rebuilding the project? I encountered this issue before in Visual Studio, when the project was referencing an old build while I was debugging, because the 'build before running' option was accidentally toggled off in Visual Studio. A good indication of this is if you set a breakpoint on the line where you call `set_black_hole()`, and the breakpoint becomes transparent when you try to debug.

Comment: I'm recompiling. The breakpoint isn't ignored, it just skips the set_black_hole() call and stops immediately after at the if() statement.